# Surface Pro 4 Keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, unresponsive, microsoft-surface-pro-4

The keyboard just isn't working. I've reset it like 10 times trying to get it to work. I've been doing the "Power On and Volume Up" technique but that just doesn't seem to be working. However, when I see that screen (The One when I press Power On and Volume Up) the keyboard works perfectly. But the moment I shut it down or press restart on that screen I get back to the home screen and the keyboard still doesn't work. (Not sure if this helps but Caps lock isn't lighting up when I pressing it, but the Function key DOES light up when pressed). There could be a good chance the way I'm doing the technique is wrong but I feel like I'm following it exactly like the semi-vague three step solutions have been showing online.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the past with my Surface Pro 3. Updating the firmware fixed the issue for me. Try updating the firmware. Firmware upgrade link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49498 .

Comment: What should I do after downloading it? Should I restart my computer or what? Also, again not sure if this is helpful or not, but this is a new computer, ~Under a month old.

Comment: Run through the msi installer and restart the Surface if the msi installer doesn't automatically do it for you. This page https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/performance-and-maintenance/install-software-updates-for-surface?os=windows-10&=undefined has more detailed instructions on how to install the firmware updates. Since your Surface is new you may already have them. But from my experience many new PC's don't have the latest updates when you get them.

Comment: @huskerman007 Kindly write the details in your answer, you can edit your answer with the new information